# Почему между переходом из одного Activity во второй на мгновенье появляется третий?

Tags: android, activity, android-intent

Ситуация следующая. Есть три `Activity` - `StartActivity`, `MiddleActivity`, `EndActivity`.

Перехожу `Intent`'ом из `StartActivity` в `MiddleActivity`. Все в норме. Перехожу из `MiddleActivity` в `EndActivity`, на мгновение появляется `StartActivity`. Переход по `Intent` аналогичный первому переходу. В чем может быть проблема?

Из `StartActivity` в `MiddleActivity`:

```
    Intent FromStartActivityToMiddleActivity = new Intent(StartActivity.this, MiddleActivity.class);
    startActivity(FromStartActivityToMiddleActivity);
    finish();
```

Из `MiddleActivity` в `EndActivity`:

```
    Intent FromMiddleActivityToEndActivity = new Intent(MiddleActivity.this, EndActivity.class);
    startActivity(FromMiddleActivityToEndActivity);
    finish();
```

Comment: Показывайте код ваших переходов.

Comment: @eugeneek: обновил вопрос

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `finish();` при переходе с первого активити на второе

Comment: @Denis422: отлично, помогло, почитаю повнимательнее доки про это. Спасибо. (оформите ответ, отметим)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это происходит из-за того, что Вы завершаете текущее второе активити, а приложению необходимо что-то отображать, поэтому оно и подгружает первое активтити.
Чтобы избавиться от этого, нужно убрать `finish();` при переходе

Если Вы используете `finish()`, чтобы очистить стэк, то можно добавить флаг в интнет на очистку бэкстэка:

`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Comment: флаг вместе с finish() требуется ставить? В таком случае продолжает мелькать первое Активити.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй

```
Intent FromStartActivityToMiddleActivity = new Intent(this, MiddleActivity.class);
    startActivity(FromStartActivityToMiddleActivity);
    finish();
```

Comment: Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(anonymous android.view.View.OnTouchListener, java.lang.Class<com.example.myproject.MiddleActivity>)'

Comment: так понимаю что ты в onClick() запускаешь активити, попробуй тогда:  Intent FromStartActivityToMiddleActivity = new Intent(view.getContext(), MiddleActivity.class);
    startActivity(FromStartActivityToMiddleActivity);
    finish();   или вместо view.getContext() используй getApplicationContext()

Comment: ни `view.getContext()`, ни `getApplicationContext()`. По прежнему мелькает StartActivity. Следовал вашему совету я в переходе `FromMiddleActivityToEndActivity`. Там мелькает `StartActivity`, там проблема

Comment: Спасибо вам. После удаления finish(); по совету `Denis 422` все нормализовалось.